# Какой кроссплатформенный UI фреймворк на C# выбрать?

Tags: c#, framework, avalonia

Ищем на какой фреймворк переходить, поставили такие требования (Windows и MacOS клиенты):

1. Должен работать, начиная с Windows 7 (хоть и неофициально)
2. Должен работать, хотя бы начиная с версии MacOS 10.10 (версии старше пока хз какие должны поддерживаться - нужно раскопать)
3. Он должен писаться на языке C# и, в  идеале, походить на .NET MAUI
4. Он должен быть стабильным и активно поддерживаемым. Идеально, если это халявный продукт, который продвигают большие компании типа Microsoft
5. Должны быть минимальные траблы с кроссплатформенностью (тут сложно оценить, скорее как пожелание большое)

Пока выбор падает на Avalonia, но есть беспокойства по поводу маленького сообщества разрабов и большого кол-ва багов: подскажите, насколько это критично, и может быть лучше выбрать что то другое.

Comment: MAUI используйте, в чем проблема? Выбор невелик. Win7 в прошлом, как и 8.

Comment: Багов кстати везде навалом, хоть в Avalonia, хоть в MAUI

Comment: @aepot maui не кроссплатформа, Avalonia поддерживает линукс, поэтому я считаю авалония лучше. У мауи такая же политика как и у майкрософтов при создании шарпа "пусть тока под винду", в итоге жидко обмякли и пришлось все переписывать на кроссплатформу. Вобщем кроссплатформа по-майкрософтски

Comment: Как будто "большая компания" это хорошо. WPF тому пример - баги так и остались, да еще сверху насыпали, когда захаркодили цвета в шаблоны контролов в вин 10. А вообще десктопным может называться только тот фреймворк, который дает DataGrid из коробки. MAUI же предлагает платные решения.

Comment: Выходит так, что лучше взять действительно кроссплатформенный UI на другом языке, что-то типа Electron или QT. А бизнес-код писать на C#.

Comment: @Aarnihauta maui не кроссплатформа???? https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/maui/what-is-maui _NET Multi-Platform App UI (.NET MAUI) — это кросс-платформенная платформа для создания собственных мобильных и классических приложений с помощью C# и XAML._

Comment: @Aarnihauta https://github.com/jsuarezruiz/maui-linux а еще автор в вопросе про Linux ничего не сказал, единственное что сказал - то что семера нужна, а это сразу оставляет только 1 вариант - авалонию.

Comment: @aepot кроссплатформа, это когда я могу свою помойку запустить на микроволновке под линуксом и на пк под виндой. К сожалению мауи может запустить только под андроид, виндовс, и apple. Все мантры майков про кроссплатформу и красивое стильное название - маркетинг, за которым стоит **отсутствие поддержки Linux**. Определенно, в вопросе есть слова только про мак и винду, но кто его знает что будет через полтора года?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы посоветовал выбрать Avalonia по некоторым причинам:

1. Поддерживается активно и относительно давно, MAUI сырой (имеет **очень** урезанный функционал по сравнению с WPF)
2. Имеет поддержку Linux, MacOS, MAUI не поддерживает Linux (по словам Microsoft: *поддержкой Linux займется коммьюнити*)
3. Есть бета-версия поддержки Android, IOS, MAUI уже имеет поддержку этих платформ поскольку является продолжением Xamarin
4. На ранних стадиях поддержка браузера через WASM